# How to forbid robots.txt on staging domain

Tags: regex, .htaccess, robots.txt

I'd like to use the same robots.txt for staging and production thus I'd like to add an condition if HTTP_HOST = staging.mydomain.com so that only the staging environment is forbitten for robots?

Is this possible?

If not, what would be the right syntax for .htaccess to have a second file like robots_staging.txt and letting the webserver do the switching?

Thx, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what you seem to need is two robots.txt files—one for each domain. Then, in `.htaccess`, you direct the request to either file depending on which domain it was made on.

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} staging.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt robots_staging\.txt [L]
```

- Anyone asking for robots.txt on the production site gets it without a rewrite
- Anyone asking for robots.txt on the staging domain gets redirected to robots_staging.txt
- In robots_staging.txt, place all the deny rules you like